# Restricting access to webpage (Google Chrome only)

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to make a webpage accessible in one browser only, for example Google Chrome? How to do it?

Comment: eh, i guess. you can spoof user agents tho

Comment: Why do you want to block a specific browser?  That goes against the principles of the open internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent users from being able to access a webpage via web browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661655/prevent-users-from-being-able-to-access-a-webpage-via-web-browser)

Answer (score 4):

as the web goes this is something that is highly discouraged. If you're relying on specific features to be available on the specific browser you should leverage on feature detection techniques, instead of browser sniffing techniques which are unreliable and flaky (browsers and crawlers can spoof that).

If you are really up for that, you can read the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string, and other techniques as suggested in this question: [reliable user browser detection with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php)